# Como rodar um crawler em Python com PHP

Tags: php, python, laravel

Fiz um crawler com Python e executo ele por linha de comando:

```
python crawler.py
```

Assim que executo este comando ele me pede a palavra chave que será procurada e começar a rodar.

```
global keyword
keyword = raw_input('Keyword: ')
```

Esses dados são usados em uma plataforma Laravel/PHP. Mas eu gostaria de criar um botão tipo "Atualizar" para que o próprio usuário pudesse executar o crawler apenas clicando em algum botão e inserindo a palavra chave.

Comment: Seria possível o *script* Python receber a *keywork* por argumento de linha de comando e executá-lo, no PHP, com a função `exec`? Algo como `exec("python crawler.py {$keyword}")`.

Comment: Porque não faz o crawler em PHP?

Comment: Concordo com o @GuilhermeNascimento, porquê forçar o uso de outra coisa e não fazer no Laravel com php?

Comment: @LucasLopes respondi, pode testar.

Comment: Só de curiosidade, não é melhor já fazer o crawler em PHP mesmo, se é pra usar no PHP?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss executei o comando mas não funcionou. Coloquei a `$keyword = "urgente"` e depois executei a linha que você disse, mas não funcionou.

Comment: @LucasLopes você leu http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180360/3635 ?

Comment: @LucasLopes tinha um erro no script, troque fclose por pclose, editei a resposta.

Comment: Colega, a sua pergunta está bem confusa. Ela não deixa claro se a sua intenção de "botão para o usuário utilizar" seria em uma página Web ou numa interface gráfica no Python. Também não está claro se a sua dificuldade é na integração do PHP com o Python ou no uso do Python em si (entrada de dados direta pelo usuário versus recebimento de dados via linha de comando). Talvez sem querer ela leva o foco para o crowler (cujo código e objetivo nem constam na pergunta, porque talvez não seja mesmo importante), quando que me parece que o foco deveria ser na integração entre as linguagens.

Comment: Todos os questionamentos e suposições ("se isso... se aquilo.. não seria melhor se...") que vc recebeu em comentários (e mesmo na resposta!) reforçam o fato de que a sua pergunta não está clara. Vc já recebeu uma boa resposta e até já a aceitou, por isso não vou votar pra fechar a pergunta como não clara. Mas no futuro, procure tomar mais cuidado e explicar direitinho a sua necessidade, ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver criando o crawler ou se ele for simples, talvez seja melhor escrever totalmente em PHP, mas é apenas uma sugestão.

Agora se quiser enviar um "input" para outro programa ao invés de usar `system`, `exec` ou `shell_exec`, você deverá usar `popen`, que lhe permitirá "conversar" com o stream, ou seja poderá enviar comandos para programas como `telnet` (só um exemplo)

> Não é necessário fgets ou fread, o próprio `popen` quando fechado envia o resultado para output (`STDOUT`), se quiser capturar a saida pode então usar `ob_start`

Um exemplo deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

$input = 'Comando enviado';

$dir = dirname(__FILE__); //Apenas para pegar a pasta relativa

$comando = 'python ' . $dir . '/crawler.py'; //Gera o comando

$handle = popen($comando, 'w'); //inicia o processo

fwrite($handle, $input);

pclose($handle);
```

E um exemplo de Python (aqui eu uso o 3.6, mas é só trocar o `input` por `raw_input` se for Python2):

```
import sys

keyword = input('Keyword: ')

print(keyword)
```

Todavia se for usar com outros programas ou sistemas talvez você enfrente algum problema, então para windows talvez você possa usar `start /B` e like-unix possa usar `2>&1`, assim:

```
<?php
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

$comando = $dir . '/crawler.py';
$input = 'Olá mundo!';

if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    $comando = 'start /B python ' . escapeshellarg($comando);
} else {
    $comando = 'python ' . escapeshellarg($comando) . ' 2>&1';
}

$handle = popen($comando, 'w'); //inicia o processo

fwrite($handle, $input);

pclose($handle);
```